# Cannot upload data into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, web-services

Why do I keep seeing this error?

> Execution timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

I don't know if the problem is in the server, or in the system itself or in the web service that created. I reconfigure the server to clear the cache memory and run a test but no luck still have that problem.

This is the code where the error is tracing

```
DialogWaitForm.Show()

BillInfoTableAdapter.Fill(ReportsDataSet.BillInfo, CType(CreateBillingForm.CurrentBillTransactionID, Long))

Dim row As ReportsDataSet.BillInfoRow
row = CType(CType(BillInfoBindingSource.Current, DataRowView).Row, ReportsDataSet.BillInfoRow)

Me.BillingTransactionsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.ReportsDataSet.BillingTransactions, CType(CreateBillingForm.ComboBoxClient.SelectedValue, Long), statementid(), row.BeginDate.Year)

Dim row4 As ReportsDataSet.BillingTransactionsRow
row4 = CType(CType(BillingTransactionsBindingSource.Current, DataRowView).Row, ReportsDataSet.BillingTransactionsRow)
BillingTransactionsBindingSource.MoveFirst()

Me.BillingAIRBILLSPerServiceTableAdapter.Fill(Me.ReportsDataSet.BillingAIRBILLSPerService, row.ID)

Me.BillingCurrentChargesTableAdapter.Fill(Me.ReportsDataSet.BillingCurrentCharges, CType(Client(), Long), CType(_current(), Decimal), CType(_currentyear, Decimal), statementid())

        Me._30daysTableAdapter.Fill(Me.ReportsDataSet._30days, CType(Client(), Long), CType(_30(), Decimal), CType(_30year, Decimal), CType(statementid(), Long))
        Me._60daysTableAdapter.Fill(Me.ReportsDataSet._60days, CType(Client(), Long), CType(_60(), Decimal), CType(_60year, Decimal), CType(statementid(), Long))
        Me._90daysTableAdapter.Fill(Me.ReportsDataSet._90days, CType(Client(), Long), CType(_90(), Decimal), CType(_90year, Decimal), CType(statementid(), Long))
        Me._120daysTableAdapter.Fill(Me.ReportsDataSet._120days, CType(Client(), Long), CType(_120(), Decimal), CType(_120year, Decimal), CType(statementid(), Long))
        Me.morethan120daysTableAdapter.Fill(Me.ReportsDataSet.morethan120days, CType(Client(), Long), morethan120)
        Me.ThisYearPreviousBalanceCrTableAdapter.Fill(Me.ReportsDataSet.ThisYearPreviousBalanceCr, CType(Client(), Long), row4.StatementOrRecptDate.Date)

        Me.BillingCurrentCRTableAdapter.Fill(Me.ReportsDataSet.BillingCurrentCR, CType(Client(), Long), CType(_current(), Decimal), CType(_currentyear, Decimal), CType(statementid(), Long))
        Me._30daysCRTableAdapter.Fill(Me.ReportsDataSet._30daysCR, CType(Client(), Long), CType(_30(), Decimal), CType(_30year, Decimal), CType(statementid(), Long))
        Me._60daysCRTableAdapter.Fill(Me.ReportsDataSet._60daysCR, CType(Client(), Long), CType(_60(), Decimal), CType(_60year, Decimal), CType(statementid(), Long))
        Me._90daysCRTableAdapter.Fill(Me.ReportsDataSet._90daysCR, CType(Client(), Long), CType(_90(), Decimal), CType(_90year, Decimal), CType(statementid(), Long))
        Me._120daysCRTableAdapter.Fill(Me.ReportsDataSet._120daysCR, CType(Client(), Long), CType(_120(), Decimal), CType(_120year, Decimal), CType(statementid(), Long))
        Me.morethan120daysCRTableAdapter.Fill(Me.ReportsDataSet.morethan120daysCR, CType(Client(), Long), morethan120, row.StatementID)
        Me.ThisYearPreviousBalanceDrTableAdapter.Fill(Me.ReportsDataSet.ThisYearPreviousBalanceDr, CType(Client(), Long), row4.StatementOrRecptDate)

        fillbilltransaction()

        If CreateBillingForm.RadioButtonWithPOD.Checked = True Then
            filltempWithPOD()
        Else
            filltempNoPOD()
        End If


        DialogWaitForm.Dispose()

        Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
```

now I have this error

> The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.
>   For more information about the error, either turn on
>   IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute
>   or from the  configuration behavior) on the server in
>   order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on
>   tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and
>   inspect the server trace logs.
>
> what happened to my server please help TIA.

this is the stack trace error

```
System.ServiceModel.FaultException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233087
  Message=The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the <serviceDebug> configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
    Server stack trace: 
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
    Exception rethrown at [0]: 
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
       at JRS_Online_Apps_III.ServiceReferenceBilling.IService.RequestGenerateBill(String rclid, String ruserid, String rbrid, String rdatefrom, String rdateto, String rduedate, String careof, Int64[] rairbillsids, Decimal rNet, Decimal rRvat, Int32 rstatement, String bir)
       at JRS_Online_Apps_III.ServiceReferenceBilling.ServiceClient.RequestGenerateBill(String rclid, String ruserid, String rbrid, String rdatefrom, String rdateto, String rduedate, String careof, Int64[] rairbillsids, Decimal rNet, Decimal rRvat, Int32 rstatement, String bir) in C:\Users\REGIME\Desktop\New folder\JRS_Online_Apps_III\JRS_Online_Apps_III\Service References\ServiceReferenceBilling\Reference.vb:line 254
       at JRS_Online_Apps_III.CreateBillingForm.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\REGIME\Desktop\New folder\JRS_Online_Apps_III\JRS_Online_Apps_III\Billing\CreateBillingForm.vb:line 238
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)
       at JRS_Online_Apps_III.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in 17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:line 81
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Updated Code

```
sqlconnect()
sqltable = New DataTable
sqladapter = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM AIRBILLS WHERE AirbillNo = '" & "123456" & "'",sqlcon)
sqladapter.Fill(sqltable)
MsgBox(sqltable.Rows(0)("Addressee"))
```

this is my error

https://ibb.co/ih3aQG

Comment: Perhaps you can set the timeout = 0, that would solve your problem

Comment: You can use SQL Server Profiler to monitor all that your application sends to server. Filter for it's login and launch the query. If you see nothing, the server was not reached at all, if you see your query, look at it's duration.

Comment: @CookieMonster where can I find the timeout properties?

Comment: @sepupic  I see queries from the profiler , does it mean that my database configuration is correct and theres no problem in my queries..? it's my first time encounter this I use to retrieve and upload data fast but now i can upload data but my other sytem won't run

Comment: Does the timeout always occur on the same query?

Comment: @jmcilhinney yes it is... I just try to try the query and its not working whenever I  want to retrieve data it end up to this error execution timeout expired.  I update my code.

Comment: The Exception Assistant window provides specific instructions on how to receive more detailed information about the issue. Have you followed those instructions?

Comment: I'm just new to this kind of error please help me to fixed this

Comment: Correct me if im wrong ... is the alter can corrupt the whole databse with relationship beacuase  I alter table but I forgot to set up the constraint and relationss

Answer (score 0):

Your last Sql Select Statement doesn't look ok ... isn't there a "=" sign missing? Like "SELECT * FROM AIRBILLS WHERE AirbillNo = '" & "123456" & "'", ...

Apart from that you should think about using SqlParameters for passing Parameters ...

Comment: it's just an example of my code  so I cannot use parameter even parameratized query is not working... I just post my screen shot and sorry for the missing "=" sign